# Does python's Web3 port fully implement the Web3 API?

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, web3js, web3py

There are different ports of Web3, including python (see https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). My questions:

It is a full implementation of the Web3 API?

Is it aligned with Web3.js?

Answer (score 1):

Web3.py API is derived from the Web3.js. It is a full implementation of web3 api. In other words it like you are using web3.js in python

Comment: It's however worth mentioning that right now the API is not asynchronous, like in Javascript. It implies all requests are blocking, which can be a huge problem depending on the project.